# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am getting such an error in the keras codes ,wrote in pycharm.Tried the solutions on the internet but I couldn't find a solution. Do you have any suggestions?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XWT2.png)

[Pip List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzaYv.png)

Comment: You have to downgrade to 1.13.2. Try doing `pip install tensorflow==1.13.2
`

Comment: Please post the complete error message as text, also include the output of `pip list`. Use the [edit] button to change your question accordingly

Comment: You are using a version of Keras that does not support that version of TensorFlow.

Comment: I added pip list screenshot.

Comment: Version 1.13.2 failed unfortunately. https://prnt.sc/BqomWRgMT8w7

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Which version of each would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the tensorflow and pillow using `pip install tensorflow` and `pip install pillow` then do a little changes as below while importing libraries to fix this error:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.applications import resnet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
```

**Note:** Please mention the error code in your question not in the form of a screenshot which will be easy to replicate the issue.